# Looking for Dropbox-like javascript tree browser / file navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to Dropbox-like javascript tree browser / file navigation. I used jsTree in the past but, for this project, I'm looking something much lighter and easier to configure tune. Preferably with all CSS.

In short, I'm looking something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [jQuery File Tree](http://jqueryfiletree.github.io/) along with my own custom style. To get something that look's and feel's as you want you should always do it yourself. Find a plugin that you are comfortable with and re-skin the output with CSS. The dropbox style is relatively easy to re-create in CSS.